# Run JavaScript only if a Div is found in the page

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am working on a module for Magento in PHP and JavaScript.

The JavaScript portion is using the default PrototypeJS library that Magento ships with.  This is my first time using Prototype.

Anyways this portion of code below alters a Div that my module inserts into **some pages**

That is the problem I am running into now, when this code runs on a page that does Not have the Div in the page that it is trying to modify.

Please help me to modify so that it can only run this code if it finds the Div with class name `.nam-modal-body`

```
// Set Modal Div CSS Width
$$('.nam-modal-body')[0].setStyle({
   width: this.options.modalWidth + "px",
  'margin-left': -(this.options.modalWidth / 2) + "px"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the errors I had to end up using this...

```
if (typeof($$('.nam-modal-body')[0]) != 'undefined') {
    $$('.nam-modal-body')[0].setStyle({
       width: this.options.modalWidth + "px",
      'margin-left': -(this.options.modalWidth / 2) + "px"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('nam-modal-body');
if (myDiv[0].length > 0) {
    $$('.nam-modal-body')[0].setStyle({
       width: this.options.modalWidth + "px",
      'margin-left': -(this.options.modalWidth / 2) + "px"
    });
}
```

**or**

```
if ($$('.nam-modal-body').length > 0) {
    $$('.nam-modal-body')[0].setStyle({
       width: this.options.modalWidth + "px",
      'margin-left': -(this.options.modalWidth / 2) + "px"
    });
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`  Keep in mind I am not using jQuery but PrototypeJS

Comment: Sorry, I don't know prototype but this can be converted to Vanilla JS rather easily.

Comment: use `if (myDiv.length > 0) {` or `if ($$('.nam-modal-body').length > 0) {`

Comment: @metadings No, in the vanilla JS example (top), `getElementsByClassName` gathers a nodeList, not a single element and the `[0]` indicator is necessary.

Comment: the NodeList is the object with a `length` property. so when you take the first element in the nodelist `[0]`, a dom element, this does not have a `length` property and throws an error, when `[0]` doesn't exist (null, undefined)